# A value of type 'Future<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'

Tags: dart, flutter-getx

A value of type 'Future?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'.

```
Widget _selectedScreen =  Get.toNamed(SummaryScreen(selectedScreenFlag: "Summary"));
```

Comment: `toNamed` might be a Future so you would have to await it in order to get the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

`Get.toNamed();` or `Get.to()` is used when you want to navigate to the other screen using GetX route style, so it's not type of widget.

So instead of doing like this:

```js
Widget _selectedScreen = Get.toNamed(SummaryScreen(selectedScreenFlag: "Summary"));
```

You can do it like this:

```js
dynamic _selectedScreen = await Get.toNamed(SummaryScreen(selectedScreenFlag: "Summary"));
```